# How to know when to start and end a Service?

Tags: android, performance, android-service

I have an image browsing app that allows a user to download images at any time  using a Foreground Service (to allow the user to navigate away from the Activity or even tab out of the app).

Is it better to start the service when the app launches and allow it to run at all times since the user can potentially download images whenever, or is it better to start/stop the Service when the user enters an Activity that is likely to prompt the user to download an image? What are the pros and cons of each?

As of now, I start the Service when entering a "Image viewing activity" and stop it when exiting but I'm not sure if this will prove to be costly later on.

Comment: I would suggest you read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services as it would give you some great advice on what kind of service you should use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the use of a foreground service in your case.

If you're just going to download the images when the user is inside your app, then you don't even need a Service, use an AsyncTask instead, or even a library like Picasso.

If you want to download images while the user has navigated away from your app, you should use a Service and also I suggest to show a notification with the download progress (like Facebook or Google Drive).

Comment: I edited my question to explain that I'd like to be able to navigate away from the app during the download, sorry.

Comment: Then it is the second option on my answer :)